# Ошибка System.FormatException Входная строка имела неверный формат

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

```
        string res = "";
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("rep.txt"))
        {
            res = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        string[] r = res.Split('|');

        if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.mel) > 0) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.mel) <= 20)) res += r[0];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.mel) > 20) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.mel) <= 40)) res += r[1];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.mel) > 40) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.mel) <= 60)) res += r[2];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.mel) > 60) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.mel) <= 80)) res += r[3];
        else res += r[4];
        res += "\n";

        if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.fleg) > 0) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.fleg) <= 20)) res += r[5];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.fleg) > 20) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.fleg) <= 40)) res += r[6];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.fleg) > 40) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.fleg) <= 60)) res += r[7];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.fleg) > 60) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.fleg) <= 80)) res += r[8];
        else res += r[9];
        res += "\n";

        if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.hol) > 0) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.hol) <= 20)) res += r[10];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.hol) > 20) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.hol) <= 40)) res += r[11];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.hol) > 40) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.hol) <= 60)) res += r[12];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.hol) > 60) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.hol) <= 80)) res += r[13];
        else res += r[14];
        res += "\n";

        if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.san) > 0) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.san) <= 20)) res += r[15];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.san) > 20) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.san) <= 40)) res += r[16];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.san) > 40) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.san) <= 60)) res += r[17];
        else if ((Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.san) > 60) && (Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.san) <= 80)) res += r[18];
        else res += r[19];
        res += "\n";
```

> Ошибка  "System.FormatException Входная строка имела неверный формат"
>   на первом условии

В переменных число вида 54.4

Comment: Разгадка находится во "входной строке" `DataForm.mel`.  Что в ней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Convert.ToDouble(DataForm.mel, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
```